# Why the Javascript code returned from DOT NET Core controller doesn't get executed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've recently started to learn the dotNET core. In a web application, while I am returning some javascript code as a string from a controller, browser shows the whole text. What is the reason?

Here's an example code:

```
public string Welcome()
{
            return "<script>'Hello World'</script>";
}
```

The browser shows the whole string in its body. Why?

Comment: what does this mean? I am returning some javascript code as a string from a controller?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't have any effect on the page, rather the whole code is shown in the body. I want to know the reason.